# Why is C++0x's `noexcept` checked dynamically?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I am curious about the rationale behind `noexcept` in the [C++0x FCD](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf). `throw(X)` was deprecated, but `noexcept` seems to do the same thing. Is there a reason that `noexcept` isn't checked at compile time? It seems that it would be better if these functions were checked statically that they only called throwing functions within a `try` block.

Comment: Also, page 1107 has a nice footnote that is pretty funny.

Comment: Ha ha!  Nice find.  That's as good as the redefinition of "ill-formed program" to be "a wannabe C++ program that is not
well-formed" in N3035.

Comment: The problem with checking these statically is that 1) it can't really be done robustly, and 2) even if that was done, it'd still be a major pain to work with -- witness the problems with Java's equivalent. No one really wants statically checked exception specifiers in C++. The question is more whether exception specifiers should be there *at all*

Comment: Actually, the problem with the funny footnotes is that it makes it easy to mistake a real footnote for a funny one, e.g., "342) Among other implications, atomic variables shall not decay."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I remember throw has been deprecated because there is no way to specify all the exceptions a template function can throw. Even for non-template functions you will need the throw clause because you have added some traces.

On the other hand the compiler can optimize code that doesn't throw exceptions. See "[The Debate on noexcept, Part I](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=481)" (along with parts [II](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=482) and [III](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=483)) for a detailed discussion. The main point seems to be:

> The vast experience of the last two decades shows that in practice, only two forms of exceptions specifications are useful:
>
> - The lack of an overt exception specification, which designates a function that can throw any type of exception:
>
>   ```
>   int func(); //might throw any exception
>   ```
> - A function that never throws. Such a function can be indicated by a throw() specification:
>
>   ```
>   int add(int, int) throw(); //should never throw any exception
>   ```

Comment: I don't see how this answer explains the reason for why noexcept is not statically checked. Also, Mr Kalev's phrase "noexcept which serves as a compile-time exception specification" seems to contradict the C++ standard as well as this question.

Answer (score 27):

Basically, it's a **linker** problem, the standards committee was reluctant to break the ABI. (If it were up to me, I would do so, all it really requires is library recompilation, we have this situation already with thread enablement, and it's manageable.)

Consider how it would work out. Suppose the requirements were

1. every destructor is implicitly `noexcept(true)`

   - Arguably, this should be a strict requirement. Throwing destructors are *always* a bug.
2. every extern "C" is implicitly `noexcept(true)`

   - Same argument again: exceptions in C-land are *always* a bug.
3. every other function is implicitly `noexcept(false)` unless otherwise specified
4. a `noexcept(true)` function must wrap all its `noexcept(false)` calls in `try{}catch(...){}`

   - By analogy, a const method cannot call a non-const method.
5. This attribute must manifest as a distinct type in overload resolution, function pointer compatibility, etc.

Sounds reasonable, right?

To implement this, the linker needs to distinguish between `noexcept(true)` and `noexcept(false)` versions of functions, much as you can overload const and const versions of member functions.

So what does this mean for name-namgling? To be backwards-compatible with existing object code we would require that all existing names are interpreted as `noexcept(false)` with extra mangling for the `noexcept(true)` versions.

This would imply we cannot link against existing destructors unless the header is modified to tag them as `noexcept(false)`

- this would break backwards compatibility,
- this arguably ought to be impossible, see point 1.

I spoke to a standards committe member in person about this and he says that this was a rushed decision, motivated mainly by a constraint on move operations in containers (you might otherwise end up with missing items after a throw, which violates the basic guarantee). Mind you, this is a man whose stated design philosophy is that *fault intolerant code is good*. Draw your own conclusions.

Like I said, I would have broken the ABI in preference to breaking the language. `noexcept` is only a marginal improvement on the old way. Static checking is always better.

Comment: static checking would be better if it were possible.  If a noyhrow function in module A calls a nothrow function in library B, thats fine.  Until library B changes to be a throwing operation.

Comment: "_every extern "C" is implicitly noexcept(true)_" I (and others) would object to this. There is nothing stopping you throwing an exception from an `extern "C"` function, and on some implementations you can do so even if it's called by C code, letting the exception propagate back to C++ code that knows how to handle it. The exception-handling model used by GCC and Clang is explicitly design to support that, and Solaris supports it too. This is well defined and useful. Without C functions being implicitly non-throwing static checking of exception specs won't work. So we don't statically check.

Comment: I don't know if it's true that GCC/Clang supporting cross-language exceptions but **it's not supported by the language**. Letting an exception propagate into code which does not define exception handling is UB. C does not define exception handling. The Right Way is to catch the exception before reaching C and wrapping it into some other structure. Throwing exceptions from C is absurd.

Comment: Can this be checked statically by the compilers with the current C++11, generating warnings if these constraints are not met (except for the overload resolution)?
If it can, then it's almost as good as an error (if that warning is turned into an error).

Comment: Perhaps I'm some kind of extremist but I don't think correctness should be a compiler option.

Comment: POSIX cancellation points are implemented with exceptions on some platforms. That means those C functions can throw. Of course prior to C11 using threads caused 'undefined behavior' in C too, but people still did it. Adding an implicit `noexcept(true)` to C functions would cause useful, conforming language extensions to become non-conforming. (It would be similar to C11 having added requirements that prevented threads as an extension instead of having added explicit support for threads.) Also, destructors throwing is _not_ always a bug, and is in fact sometimes useful.

Comment: How can POSIX cancellation points be implemented with exceptions if they're written in C? (If they're not written in C, your complaint isn't relevant.) And perhaps "bug" isn't the right word but a throwing destructor always indicates you're doing something fundamentally wrong. Okay it may be *useful* but only within the context of a faulty design. Fix the design, don't break the language to accommodate it. Not every idea should be expressible.

Comment: The original paper http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2855.html proposes exactly the static variant of `noexcept` OP is asking about. So is this one more (big, IMHO) thing we could implement if c++ chose to do an ABI break?

Answer (score 8):

Note that `noexcept` checks for an exception thrown by a failing `dynamic_cast` and `typeid` applied to a `null` pointer, which can only be done at runtime. Other tests can indeed be done at compile time.

Comment: However, it is possible to simply forbid `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` outside a `try` block...

Comment: Except that it might not be suitable to catch the exception at that point. The exception could be re-thrown, but that's adding unnecessary verbosity and overhead.

Answer (score 6):

As other answers have stated, statements such as `dynamic_cast`s can possibly throw but can only be checked at runtime, so the compiler can't tell for certain at compile time.

This means at compile time the compiler can either let them go (ie. don't compile-time check), warn, or reject outright (which wouldn't be useful).  That leaves warning as the only reasonable thing for the compiler to do.

But that's still not really useful - suppose you have a `dynamic_cast` which for whatever reason you know will *never* fail and throw an exception because your program is written so.  The compiler probably doesn't know that and throws a warning, which becomes noise, which probably just gets disabled by the programmer for being useless, negating the point of the warning.

A similar issue is if you have a function which is not specified with `noexcept` (ie. can throw exceptions) which you want to call from many functions, some `noexcept`, some not.  You know the function will never throw in the circumstances called by the `noexcept` functions, but again the compiler doesn't: more useless warnings.

So there's no useful way for the compiler to enforce this at compile time.  This is more in the realm of static analysis, which tend to be more picky and throw warnings for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a function

```
void fn() noexcept
{
   foo();
   bar();
}
```

Can you statically check if its correct? You would have to know whether foo or bar are going to throw exceptions. You could force all functions calls to be inside a try{} block, something like this

```
void fun() noexcept
{
    try
    {
         foo();
         bar();
    }
    catch(ExceptionType &)
    {
    }
}
```

But that is wrong. We have no way of knowing that foo and bar will only throw that type of exception. In order to make sure we catch anything we'd need to use "...". If you catch anything, what are you going to do with any errors you catch? If an unexpected error arises here the only thing to do is abort the program. But that is essentially what the runtime check provided by default will do.

In short, providing enough details to prove that a given function will never throw the incorrect exceptions would produce verbose code in cases where the compiler can't be sure whether or not the function will throw the wrong type. The usefulness of that static proof probably isn't worth the effort.

Comment: I disagree.  If we have a complete prototype for foo and bar then we will know if they have exception specifications.  The only way this code will compile (even if foo and bar are in dynamicly loaded libraries) is if we have proper prototypes for them at compile time.

Comment: @SoapBox: But the only non-deprecated specifications are "might throw" and "doesn't throw."  Whether or not `fun` throws when `foo` and `bar` have the "might throw" specifications is based on *what* they might throw.  If they throw `ExceptionType` objects, `fun` is fine.  If they throw `OtherExceptionType` objects, `fun` is not fine.  The prototypes are insufficient to determine this.

Comment: Also, what if the prototype changes from nothrow to not nothrow?

Answer (score 3):

There is some overlap in the functionality of `noexcept` and `throw()`, but they're really coming from opposite directions.

`throw()` was about correctness, and nothing else: a way to specify the behavior if an unexpected exception was thrown.

The primary purpose of `noexcept` is optimization: It allows/encourages the compiler to optimize around the assumption that no exceptions will be thrown.

But yes, in practice, they're not far from being two different names for the same thing. The motivations behind them are different though.

Comment: The primary purpose of `noexcept` is correctness also. Throwing moves break the strong guarantee in previously correct code (such as sorting algorithms and container resizes) so we need `std::move_if_noexcept` to rewrite old generic code in a safe way. Of course the lack of static checking makes it behave like `assert` rather than `const` but that's the price of backwards compatibility :-(

Comment: As spraff says, template code such as containers can behave differntly based on the presence or absence of `noexcept` (and equivalently `throw()`) so it's not just about compiler optimizations, but also impacts library design and choice of algorithm. The key to doing that is the `noexcept` operator that allows code to query how throwy an expression is, _that's_ the new thing, and all that cares about is a yes/no answer, it doesn't care what type of exception might be thrown, only whether one might be thrown or not