# Why does reallocating a vector copy instead of moving the elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, move-semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enforce move semantics when a vector grows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows)

`insert`, `push_back` and `emplace`(`_back`) can cause a reallocation of a `std::vector`. I was baffled to see that the following code *copies* the elements instead of *moving* them while reallocating the container.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    int value;

    explicit foo(int value) : value(value) {
        std::cout << "foo(" << value << ")\n";
    }

    foo(foo const& other) noexcept : value(other.value) {
        std::cout << "foo(foo(" << value << "))\n";
    }

    foo(foo&& other) noexcept : value(std::move(other.value)) {
        other.value = -1;
        std::cout << "foo(move(foo(" << value << "))\n";
    }

    ~foo() {
        if (value != -1)
            std::cout << "~foo(" << value << ")\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<foo> foos;
    foos.emplace_back(1);
    foos.emplace_back(2);
}
```

On my specific machine using my specific compiler (GCC 4.7) this prints the following:

```
foo(1)
foo(2)
foo(foo(1))
~foo(1)
~foo(1)
~foo(2)
```

However, when deleting the copy constructor (`foo(foo const&) = delete;`), the following (expected) output is generated:

```
foo(1)
foo(2)
foo(move(foo(1))
~foo(1)
~foo(2)
```

Why is that? Would’t moving generally be more efficient, or at least not much less efficient, than copying?

It bears noting that [GCC 4.5.1 does the expected thing](http://ideone.com/2EPxu) – is this a regression in GCC 4.7 or is it some deviously clever optimisation because the compiler sees that my object is cheap to copy (but how?!)?

Also note that I made sure that this *is* caused by reallocation, by experimentally putting a `foos.reserve(2);` in front of the insertions; this causes neither copy nor move to be executed.

Comment: It's not a regression, it's a bug fix.  The standard specifies that `std::vector` will only prefer an element move constructor which is non-throwing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Not at all a duplicate. This is asking a specific implementation related question.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yes it is.  The answers to the other question explain this completely.

Comment: @Ben Even though the answer actually explains this, the question doesn’t ask for it so I don’t think this is a duplicate: Nobody who searches for this will find the other question. (Exhibit A: yours truly.)

Comment: @Konrad: I found that question and answer by searching for "[c++] vector move regression"

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I don't think this is an issue. As far as I understood duplicates are kept and simply become pointers to the base question. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Ben Furthermore, the answer is incorrect, adding `noexcept` changes nothing, and I don’t see how the compiler could even dispatch on this … it doesn’t change the signature or anything.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That answer doesn't say to use `noexcept`, it says to use `throw()`.  Did you try that?

Comment: @BenVoigt no, `throw()` doesn't help either.

Comment: It is possible to dispatch on no-throw thanks to the `noexcept` operator (not to be confused with `noexcept` specifications) and type traits. `std::move_if_noexcept` comes in handy though.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The other answers explain the correct form. They do not explain why the incorrect form worked on GCC 4.5.1. This question, and any answer, is entirely implementation-specific.

Comment: @DeadMG: In the (invalid) bug report I linked in my answer, the gcc team explained that the correct behavior was implemented in g++ 4.7.x, and gcc 4.5.1 didn't implement the exception-safety requirements.

Comment: Also, there is a better duplicate out there somewhere, because I remember finding a link to that bug report on SO originally.  But I can't find the original any more.

Comment: The only clear explanation I saw about the behavior of gcc 4.7 is from Jonathan Wakely (libstc++ dev) here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800858/stdvectorpush-back-a-non-copyable-object-gives-compiler-error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tip-of-trunk clang + libc++ gets:

```
foo(1)
foo(2)
foo(move(foo(1))
~foo(2)
~foo(1)
```

If you remove the `noexcept` from the move constructor, then you get the copy solution:

```
foo(1)
foo(2)
foo(foo(1))
~foo(1)
~foo(2)
~foo(1)
```

Answer (score 14):

The short answer is that I think @BenVoigt is basically correct.

In the description of `reserve` (§23.3.6.3/2), it says:

> If an exception is thrown other than by the move constructor of a non-CopyInsertable type, there are no effects.

[And the description of `resize` in §23.3.6.3/12 requires the same.]

This means that if T is CopyInsertable, you get strong exception safety. To assure that, it can *only* use move construction if *it* deduces (by unspecified means) that move construction will never throw. There's no guarantee that either `throw()` or `noexcept` will be necessary or sufficient for that though. If T is CopyInsertable, it *can* simply choose to always use copy construction. Basically, what's happening is that the standard requires copy construction-like semantics; the compiler can only use move construction under the as-if rule, and it's free to define when or if it'll exercise that option.

If T is not CopyInsertable, reallocation *will* use move construction, but exception safety depends on whether T's move constructor can throw. If it doesn't throw, you get strong exception safety, but if it throws, you don't (I think you *probably* get the basic guarantee, but maybe not even that and definitely no more).

Comment: Two years later, I’m now convinced that this interpretation is wrong – it may conform to the letter of the standard but almost certainly not to the intent: `noexcept` is widely interpreted by users of C++ (including standardese experts) to be a *binding* nothrow specification, contrary to what you’ve said. In fact, library implementors widely use it as such, and while the GCC implementation used in my question might be strictly conforming, it performs sub-optimally. This is supported by the fact that subsequent versions of GCC fixed this behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a regression, it's a bug fix. The standard specifies that std::vector will only prefer an element move constructor which is non-throwing.

See also [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864895/103167) and [this bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52745).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011428/move-constructors-and-the-strong-exception-guarantee) is also relevant.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong, see updated question. `noexcept` changes nothing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Click the bug report link.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If `noexcept` changes nothing, the proper answer is not to say this answer is wrong, but to attempt `static_assert( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<foo>::value, "" );`.

Comment: @Ben The bug report (and one of the answers on the other question) make explicit reference to `noexcept`, which is why I was confused. Furthermore, using `noexcept` would be more logical, no? And just to confuse things further, **`throw()` also doesn’t work** on my machine.

Comment: @Luc Alas, no dice. The metafunction evaluates to `false`. Surely *this* is a bug, no?