# When should I really use noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, noexcept

The `noexcept` keyword can be appropriately applied to many function signatures, but I am unsure as to when I should consider using it in practice. Based on what I have read so far, the last-minute addition of `noexcept` seems to address some important issues that arise when move constructors throw. However, I am still unable to provide satisfactory answers to some practical questions that led me to read more about `noexcept` in the first place.

1. There are many examples of functions that I know will never throw, but for which the compiler cannot determine so on its own. Should I append `noexcept` to the function declaration in **all such cases?**

   Having to think about whether or not I need to append `noexcept` after **every** function declaration would greatly reduce programmer productivity (and frankly, would be a pain in the neck). For which situations should I be more careful about the use of `noexcept`, and for which situations can I get away with the implied `noexcept(false)`?
2. When can I realistically expect to observe a performance improvement after using `noexcept`? In particular, give an example of code for which a C++ compiler is able to generate better machine code after the addition of `noexcept`.

   Personally, I care about `noexcept` because of the increased freedom provided to the compiler to safely apply certain kinds of optimizations. Do modern compilers take advantage of `noexcept` in this way? If not, can I expect some of them to do so in the near future?

Comment: Code that uses `move_if_nothrow` (or whatchamacallit) will see a performance improvement if there's a noexcept move ctor.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Re-noexcept

Comment: [std::move_if_noexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept)

Comment: By Jehovah God's help, after hours looking around I could finally gather from Nicol Bolas' comment on [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788101/3168237) that ultimately, the compiler will do a good job identifying where something is noexcept(true) or noexcept(false) and optimize accordingly. The only reason we see the std::vector's noexcept optimization is because std::vector's implementation is written to do something less efficient if the method is not **programmer marked** as noexcept. If it were to 'ask' the compiler, std::vector could work with the inferred most efficient path.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

I think it is too early to give a "best practices" answer for this as there hasn't been enough time to use it in practice. If this was asked about throw specifiers right after they came out then the answers would be very different to now.

> Having to think about whether or not I need to append `noexcept` after every function declaration would greatly reduce programmer productivity (and frankly, would be a pain).

Well, then use it when it's obvious that the function will never throw.

> When can I realistically expect to observe a performance improvement after using `noexcept`? [...] Personally, I care about `noexcept` because  of the increased freedom provided to the compiler to safely apply certain kinds of optimizations.

It seems like the biggest optimization gains are from user optimizations, not compiler ones due to the possibility of checking `noexcept` and overloading on it. Most compilers follow a no-penalty-if-you-don't-throw exception handling method, so I doubt it would change much (or anything) on the machine code level of your code, although perhaps reduce the binary size by removing the handling code.

Using `noexcept` in the big four (constructors, assignment, not destructors as they're already `noexcept`) will likely cause the best improvements as `noexcept` checks are 'common' in template code such as in `std` containers. For instance, `std::vector` won't use your class's move unless it's marked `noexcept` (or the compiler can deduce it otherwise).

Comment: I think the `std::terminate` trick still obeys the Zero-Cost model. That is, it just so happens that the range of instructions within the `noexcept` functions is mapped to call `std::terminate` if `throw` is used instead of the stack unwinder. I therefore doubt it has more overhead that regular exception tracking.

Comment: "For instance, std::vector won't use your class's move unless it's marked noexcept." What? Really? Are you sure it is required?

Comment: @Klaim See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10128180/964135 Actually it just has to be non-throwing, but the `noexcept` guarantees this.

Comment: @Pubby Ok thanks for the clarification, that's quite an interesting subtlety. That explains why my code still does moves.

Comment: "If a `noexcept` function throws then `std::terminate` is called which seems like it would involve a small amount of overhead"… No, this should be implemented by not generating exception tables for such a function, which the exception dispatcher should catch and then bail out.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yeah, I guess the point I was trying to make is that it won't remove the exception handling completely. Have a suggestion to what I should change that sentence in the post to?

Comment: @Pubby C++ exception handling is usually done with no overhead except jump tables which map potentially throwing call site addresses to handler entry points. Removing those tables is as close as it gets to removing exception handling completely. The only difference is executable file size. Probably not worth mentioning anything.

Comment: Why they don't do noexcept as a default argument?

Comment: "Well then use it when it's obvious that the function will never throw." I disagree. `noexcept` is part of the function's *interface*; you should not add it just because your current *implementation* happens not to throw. I am not sure about the right answer to this question, but I am quite confident that how your function happens to behave today has nothing to do with it...

Comment: @Potatoswatter: "C++ exception handling is usually done with no overhead except jump tables" -- Not true according to some compiler authors; e.g. search for "Chandler" at http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/insights-into-new-and-c.html. The compiler knowing that control flow is linear can certainly enable some optimizations, at least in principle.

Comment: @Nemo See also my recent answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079903/noexcept-stack-unwinding-and-performance/26080018#26080018

Comment: @Nemo Any optimisation possible without exception is still possible with exceptions, it's an obvious observation.

Comment: @curiousguy: Wrong. It is trivial to think of examples if you know anything about compiler optimization... But I will just refer you to https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/noexcept-what-for/ and suggest you do some more reading on your own

Comment: @Nemo The reference does not describe any compiler optimisation.

Comment: Is this feature important enough to create a keyword for?

Comment: is it still too early?

Comment: What are the big 4? In your answer I only see 3: constructors, assignment, not destructors. Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: @NamHoang: 1. Copy constructor  2. Copy assignment  3. Move constructor   4. Move assignment

Answer (score 182):

As I keep repeating these days: **semantics first**.

Adding `noexcept`, `noexcept(true)` and `noexcept(false)` is first and foremost about semantics. It only incidentally condition a number of possible optimizations.

As a programmer reading code, the presence of `noexcept` is akin to that of `const`: it helps me better grok what may or may not happen. Therefore, it is worthwhile spending some time thinking about whether or not you know if the function will throw. For a reminder, any kind of dynamic memory allocation may throw.

---

Okay, now on to the possible optimizations.

The most obvious optimizations are actually performed in the libraries. C++11 provides a number of traits that allows knowing whether a function is `noexcept` or not, and the Standard Library implementation themselves will use those traits to favor `noexcept` operations on the user-defined objects they manipulate, if possible. Such as *move semantics*.

The compiler may only shave a bit of fat (perhaps) from the exception handling data, because it *has* to take into account the fact that you may have lied. If a function marked `noexcept` does throw, then `std::terminate` is called.

These semantics were chosen for two reasons:

- immediately benefiting from `noexcept` even when dependencies do not use it already (backward compatibility)
- allowing the specification of `noexcept` when calling functions that may theoretically throw, but are not expected to for the given arguments

Comment: Maybe I'm naive, but I would imagine a function that invokes only `noexcept` functions wouldn't need to do anything special, because any exceptions that might arise trigger `terminate` before they get to this level. This differs greatly from having to deal with and propagate a `bad_alloc` exception.

Comment: @Hurkyl: you are right. Which is why a sufficiently smart compiler might figure this out and avoid generating entries in the program-counter/exception-handler table for this function (thus reducing the fat as I said). However many functions will not be marked `noexcept` (think about system calls for example, or low-level OS-specific C functions), which is why the short-cut chosen was that the compiler did not have to check it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to define noexcept in way as you suggest, but that would be a really unusable feature. Many function can throw if certain conditions aren't hold, and you couldn't call them even if you know the conditions are met. For example any function which may throw std::invalid_argument.

Comment: @tr3w: I understand your argument, however I will oppose real-world practice => it's so easy to misunderstand the requirement and have the function throw that it should not be allowed to be in a `noexcept` function (without proper try/catch at least). And even if *now* it works, any number of refactoring/maintenance may invalidate this later on. That's the biggest advantage of compile-time checks: they are exhaustive and hold version after version.

Comment: Since compiler changes often require that everything be rebuilt anyway, why not use name mangling so declaring a method `foo_whatever` as `noexcept` would define both `foo_whatever` and `__noex__foo_whatever`, while defining a method without `noexcept` would just define the former.  If a `noexcept` methods calls `foo`, the compiler should have it call `__noex_foo_whatever` and also generate a weak definition for `__noex_foo_whatever` which calls `foo_whatever` and terminates if it throws an exception?  Then a `noexcept` which only calls other `noexcept` methods could avoid all overhead.

Comment: @MatthieuM. A bit late for a reply, but nevertheless. Functions marked noexcept can call other functions that can throw, the promise is that this function will not emit an exception i.e. they just have to handle the exception themselves!

Comment: Or pass arguments that ensure the callee won't throw even though it does for other inputs -- something that compilers aren't smart enough or don't have enough information to check, but programmers on a good day are and do. You don't always want to have to write "except" and "noexcept" versions of your functions according to whether the caller has somehow pre-validated the inputs, like `operator[]` vs. `at()`.

Comment: I upvoted this answer a long time ago, but having read and thought about it some more, I have a comment/question. "Move semantics" is the _only_ example I have ever seen anybody give where `noexcept` is clearly helpful / a good idea. I am starting to think move construction, move assignment, and swap are the only cases there are... Do you know of any others?

Comment: @Nemo: In the Standard library, it is possibly the only one, however it exhibits a principle which can be reused elsewhere. A move operation is an operation that temporarily put some state in "limbo", and only when it is `noexcept` may someone use it confidently on a piece of data that could be accessed afterward. I could see this idea being used elsewhere, but the Standard library is rather thin in C++ and it is only used to optimize out copies of elements I think.

Answer (score 115):

This actually does make a (potentially) huge difference to the optimizer in the compiler. Compilers have actually had this feature for years via the empty throw() statement after a function definition, as well as propriety extensions. I can assure you that modern compilers do take advantage of this knowledge to generate better code.

Almost every optimization in the compiler uses something called a "flow graph" of a function to reason about what is legal. A flow graph consists of what are generally called "blocks" of the function (areas of code that have a single entrance and a single exit) and edges between the blocks to indicate where flow can jump to. Noexcept alters the flow graph.

You asked for a specific example. Consider this code:

```
void foo(int x) {
    try {
        bar();
        x = 5;
        // Other stuff which doesn't modify x, but might throw
    } catch(...) {
        // Don't modify x
    }

    baz(x); // Or other statement using x
}
```

The flow graph for this function is different if `bar` is labeled `noexcept` (there is no way for execution to jump between the end of `bar` and the catch statement). When labeled as `noexcept`, the compiler is certain the value of x is 5 during the baz function - the x=5 block is said to "dominate" the baz(x) block without the edge from `bar()` to the catch statement.

It can then do something called "constant propagation" to generate more efficient code. Here if baz is inlined, the statements using x might also contain constants and then what used to be a runtime evaluation can be turned into a compile-time evaluation, etc.

Anyway, the short answer: `noexcept` lets the compiler generate a tighter flow graph, and the flow graph is used to reason about all sorts of common compiler optimizations. To a compiler, user annotations of this nature are awesome. The compiler will try to figure this stuff out, but it usually can't (the function in question might be in another object file not visible to the compiler or transitively use some function which is not visible), or when it does, there is some trivial exception which might be thrown that you're not even aware of, so it can't implicitly label it as `noexcept` (allocating memory might throw bad_alloc, for example).

Comment: Does this actually make a difference in practice? The example is contrived because *nothing* before `x = 5` can throw. If that part of the `try` block served any purpose the reasoning wouldn't hold.

Comment: I'd say it does make a real difference in optimizing functions which contain try/catch blocks. The example I gave although contrived, isn't exhaustive. The larger point is that noexcept (like the throw() statement before it) helps the compile generate a smaller flow graph (less edges, less blocks) which is a fundamental part of many optimizations it then does.

Comment: How can compiler recognize that the code can throw exception? Is and access to array considered as possible exception?

Comment: @qub1n If the compiler can see the body of the function it can look for explicit `throw` statements, or other things like `new` that can throw. If the compiler cannot see the body then it must rely on the presence or absence of `noexcept`. Plain array access does not typically generate exceptions (C++ doesn't have bounds checking) so no, array access wouldn't alone cause the compiler to think a function throws exceptions. (Out-of-bound access is UB, not a guaranteed exception.)

Comment: @cdhowie "_it must rely on the presence or absence of noexcept_" or presence of `throw()` in pre-noexcept C++

Comment: @TerryMahaffey "_real difference in optimizing functions which contain try/catch blocks_" ... that fully handle the exception, not Java "finally"-like blocks that rethrow, which is 99% of try/catch in lib code

Answer (score 70):

`noexcept` can dramatically improve performance of some operations. This does not happen at the level of generating machine code by the compiler, but by selecting the most effective algorithm: as others mentioned, you do this selection using function `std::move_if_noexcept`. For instance, the growth of `std::vector` (e.g., when we call `reserve`) must provide a strong exception-safety guarantee. If it knows that `T`'s move constructor doesn't throw, it can just move every element. Otherwise it must copy all `T`s. This has been described in detail in [this post](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/10/exceptionally-moving/).

Comment: Addendum: That means if you define move constructors or move assignment operators add `noexcept` to them (if applicable)! Implicitly defined move member functions have [`noexcept` added to them automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18654089/3041008) (if applicable).

Answer (score 50):

> When can I realistically except to observe a performance improvement after using `noexcept`? In particular, give an example of code for which a C++ compiler is able to generate better machine code after the addition of noexcept.

Um, never? Is never a time? Never.

`noexcept` is for *compiler* performance optimizations in the same way that `const` is for compiler performance optimizations. That is, almost never.

`noexcept` is primarily used to allow "you" to detect at compile-time if a function can throw an exception. Remember: most compilers don't emit special code for exceptions unless it actually throws something. So `noexcept` is not a matter of giving the compiler hints about how to optimize a function so much as giving *you* hints about how to use a function.

Templates like `move_if_noexcept` will detect if the move constructor is defined with `noexcept` and will return a `const&` instead of a `&&` of the type if it is not. It's a way of saying to move if it is very safe to do so.

In general, you should use `noexcept` when you think it will actually be *useful* to do so. Some code will take different paths if `is_nothrow_constructible` is true for that type. If you're using code that will do that, then feel free to `noexcept` appropriate constructors.

In short: use it for move constructors and similar constructs, but don't feel like you have to go nuts with it.

Comment: Strictly, `move_if_noexcept` won't return a copy, it will return a const lvalue-reference rather than an rvalue-reference.  In general that will cause the caller to make a copy instead of a move, but `move_if_noexcept` isn't doing the copy. Otherwise, great explanation.

Comment: +1 Jonathan. Resizing a vector, for example, will move the objects instead of copying them if the move constructor is `noexcept`. So that "never" is not true.

Comment: @mfontanini: That's not a *compiler* optimization though, which is what he was asking about.

Comment: I mean, the compiler **will** generate better code in that situation. OP is asking for an example for which the compiler is able to generate a more optimized application. This seems to be the case(even though it's not a *compiler* optimization).

Comment: @mfontanini: The compiler only generates better code because the compiler is forced to compile a *different codepath*. It *only* works because `std::vector` is written to force the compiler to compile *different* code. It's not about the compiler detecting something; it's about user code detecting something.

Comment: "give an example of code for which a C++ compiler is able to generate better machine code after the addition of noexcept" -> I know it's not the compilers fault that the application does things more efficienttly, but it's the compiler who generates it after all.

Comment: And since the library is a specified part of the C++ standard, I don't really care if it was the compiler or the library, as long as tagging my move constructor `noexcept` gives faster code **across all implementations**.

Comment: @mfontanini: "it's the compiler who generates it after all." By that logic, using a better algorithm is a compiler optimization. *Anything* is a compiler optimization. Thus the term has no useful meaning.

Comment: The thing is, I can't seem to find "compiler optimization" in the quote at the begining of your answer. As @ChristianRau said, it the compiler generates a more efficient code, it doesn't matter what's the origin of that optimization. After all, the compiler *is* generating a more efficient code, isn't it? PS: I never said it was a compiler optimization, I even said "It's not a compiler optimization".

Comment: @NicolBolas I feel like you're really arguing semantics here. I know it's not exactly the compiler that generates better code. I also know what you want to say conceptually and that arguing semantics isn't such a bad thing in C++. But let's be honest, `move_if_noexcept` is *exactly* the kind of stuff the question is looking for. If it is strictly the *compiler* or the *library* doesn't matter, since from a practical viewpoint both are the same *in this scenario* to any user who doesn't actually *develop* the C++ standard library, which hardly anyone does.

Answer (score 43):

In [Bjarne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup)'s words (*The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition*, page 366):

> Where termination is an acceptable response, an uncaught exception
> will achieve that because it turns into a call of terminate()
> (§13.5.2.5). Also, a `noexcept` specifier (§13.5.1.1) can make that
> desire explicit.
>
> Successful fault-tolerant systems are multilevel. Each level copes
> with as many errors as it can without getting too contorted and leaves
> the rest to higher levels. Exceptions support that view. Furthermore,
> `terminate()` supports this view by providing an escape if the
> exception-handling mechanism itself is *corrupted* or if it has been
> incompletely used, thus leaving exceptions uncaught. Similarly,
> *`noexcept` provides a simple escape for errors where trying to recover
> seems infeasible.*
>
> ```
> double compute(double x) noexcept
> {
>     string s = "Courtney and Anya";
>     vector<double> tmp(10);
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> The vector constructor may fail to acquire memory for its ten doubles
> and throw a `std::bad_alloc`. In that case, the program terminates. It
> terminates unconditionally by invoking `std::terminate()` (§30.4.1.3).
> It does not invoke destructors from calling functions. It is
> implementation-defined whether destructors from scopes between the
> `throw` and the `noexcept` (e.g., for s in compute()) are invoked. The
> program is just about to terminate, so we should not depend on any
> object anyway. ***By adding a `noexcept` specifier, we indicate that our
> code was not written to cope with a throw.***

Comment: This sounds to me as if I actually should add a `noexcept` every time, except I explicitly want to take care of exceptions. Let's be real, most of the exceptions are so improbable and/or so fatal that rescuing is hardly reasonable or possible. E.g. in the quoted example, if allocation fails, the application will hardly be able to continue working correctly.

Comment: This may be a naive question, but why is the focus on `vector<double> tmp(10);`? Can't the string instance creation in the line above equally throw if there's not enough memory for it?

Comment: "A program limping along, unable to allocate even tiny amounts of memory, can quickly become the enemy of reliability." -Joe Duffy (https://joeduffyblog.com/2016/02/07/the-error-model/)

Comment: @DanielDaranas Yes, the `std::string` constructor can also throw. This is just an example showing how `noexcept` is used not to care to destruct the successfully constructed `std::string` in case of the following memory allocation failure of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 30):

> 1. There are many examples of functions that I know will never throw, but for which the compiler cannot determine so on its own. Should I append noexcept to the function declaration in all such cases?

`noexcept` is tricky, as it is part of the functions interface. Especially, if you are writing a library, your client code can depend on the `noexcept` property. It can be difficult to change it later, as you might break existing code. That might be less of a concern when you are implementing code that is only used by your application.

If you have a function that cannot throw, ask yourself whether it will like stay `noexcept` or would that restrict future implementations? For example, you might want to introduce error checking of illegal arguments by throwing exceptions (e.g., for unit tests), or you might depend on other library code that could change its exception specification. In that case, it is safer to be conservative and omit `noexcept`.

On the other hand, if you are confident that the function should never throw and it is correct that it is part of the specification, you should declare it `noexcept`. However, keep in mind that the compiler will not be able to detect violations of `noexcept` if your implementation changes.

> 2. For which situations should I be more careful about the use of noexcept, and for which situations can I get away with the implied noexcept(false)?

There are four classes of functions that should you should concentrate on because they will likely have the biggest impact:

1. move operations (move assignment operator and move constructors)
2. swap operations
3. memory deallocators (operator delete, operator delete[])
4. destructors (though these are implicitly `noexcept(true)` unless you make them `noexcept(false)`)

These functions should generally be `noexcept`, and it is most likely that library implementations can make use of the `noexcept` property. For example, `std::vector` can use non-throwing move operations without sacrificing strong exception guarantees. Otherwise, it will have to fall back to copying elements (as it did in C++98).

This kind of optimization is on the algorithmic level and does not rely on compiler optimizations. It can have a significant impact, especially if the elements are expensive to copy.

> 3. When can I realistically expect to observe a performance improvement after using noexcept? In particular, give an example of code for which a C++ compiler is able to generate better machine code after the addition of noexcept.

The advantage of `noexcept` against no exception specification or `throw()` is that the standard allows the compilers more freedom when it comes to stack unwinding. Even in the `throw()` case, the compiler has to completely unwind the stack (and it has to do it in the exact reverse order of the object constructions).

In the `noexcept` case, on the other hand, it is not required to do that. There is no requirement that the stack has to be unwound (but the compiler is still allowed to do it). That freedom allows further code optimization as it lowers the overhead of always being able to unwind the stack.

The related question about [noexcept, stack unwinding and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26079903/783510) goes into more details about the overhead when stack unwinding is required.

I also recommend Scott Meyers book "Effective Modern C++", "Item 14: Declare functions noexcept if they won't emit exceptions" for further reading.

Comment: Still it would make much more sense if exceptions were implemented in C++ like in Java, where you mark method that may throw with `throws` keyword instead of `noexcept` negative. I just can not get some of C++ design choices...

Comment: They named it `noexcept` because `throw` was already taken. Simply put `throw` can be used _almost_ they way you mention, except they botched the design of it so it became almost useless - detrimental even. But we are stuck with it now since removing it would be a breaking change with little benefit. So `noexcept` is basically `throw_v2`.

Comment: How is `throw` not useful?

Comment: @curiousguy "throw" itself (for throwing exceptions) is useful, but "throw" as an exception specifier has been deprecated and in C++17 even removed. For reasons why exception specifiers are not useful, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c

Comment: @PhilippClaßen The `throw()` exception specifier did not provide the same guarantee as `nothrow`?

Comment: @curiousguy Yes, there is a difference that is relevant for compiler optimization. If you do throw, `throw()` enforces that the stack is completely unwound, whereas C++11 `noexcept` leaves it open to implementation. That is less constraining for the optimizer. See this question, which also contains the quote from Scott Meyer's book that I am referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26079903/783510

Comment: "_That freedom allows further code optimization as it lowers the overhead of always being able to unwind the stack._" That should make no difference with a zero overhead implementation.

Comment: In practice, there are no zero overhead exception implementations. Herb Sutter has a proposal that could change that: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0709r0.pdf

Comment: But even for stack unwinding when you do not throw, the compiler is restricted. It is additionally limited by calling conventions (part of the ABI). It is not an easy problem for compilers to implement the current exception model without introducing any overhead.

Answer (score 21):

> There are many examples of functions that I know will never throw, but for which the compiler cannot determine so on its own. Should I append noexcept to the function declaration in all such cases?

When you say "I know [they] will never throw", you mean by examining the implementation of the function you know that the function will not throw. I think that approach is inside out.

It is better to consider whether a function may throw exceptions to be part of the *design* of the function: as important as the argument list and whether a method is a mutator (... `const`). Declaring that "this function never throws exceptions" is a constraint on the implementation. Omitting it does not mean the function might throw exceptions; it means that the current version of the function *and* all future versions may throw exceptions. It is a constraint that makes the implementation harder. But some methods must have the constraint to be practically useful; most importantly, so they can be called from destructors, but also for implementation of "roll-back" code in methods that provide the strong exception guarantee.

Comment: This is the best answer by far. You are making a guarantee to users of your method, which is another way of saying you are constraining your implementation _forever_ (sans breaking-change). Thanks for the enlightening perspective.

Comment: See also [a related Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610768/why-does-the-java-compiler-allow-exceptions-to-be-listed-in-the-throws-section-t).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example to illustrate when it could really matter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class A{
 public:
  A(int){cout << "A(int)" << endl;}
  A(const A&){cout << "A(const A&)" << endl;}
  A(const A&&) noexcept {cout << "A(const A&&)" << endl;}
  ~A(){cout << "~S()" << endl;}
};
int main() {
  vector<A> a;
  cout << a.capacity() << endl;
  a.emplace_back(1);
  cout << a.capacity() << endl;
  a.emplace_back(2);
  cout << a.capacity() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

```
0
A(int)
1
A(int)
A(const A&&)
~S()
2
~S()
~S()
```

If we remove the noexcept in the move constructor, here is the output

```
0
A(int)
1
A(int)
A(const A&)
~S()
2
~S()
~S()
```

The key difference is `A(const A&&)` vs `A(const A&&)`. In the second case, it has to copy all the values using the copy constructor. VERY INEFFICIENT!!

Comment: Looks like you are using this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AG_63_edgUg My question is: Will using `-fno-exceptions` compiler option trigger the same performance benefit as marking the move constructor `noexcept`?

Comment: I just tested it with GCC and clang trunk and it seems like marking the function `noexcept` is still required even if using `-fno-execptions` for the move constructor to be preferred.

Comment: do you mean `A(const A&) vs A(const A&&)`?!

Comment: isn't it a [bug](https://godbolt.org/z/vx7bvshTo) to declare a move constructor with a `const` modifier?  You cannot move from a const object.

Answer (score 1):

> When can I realistically expect to observe a performance improvement after using noexcept? In particular, give an example of code for which a C++ compiler is able to generate better machine code after the addition of noexcept.

has already been answered very well by existing answers. In my answer, I will only address this

> There are many examples of functions that I know will never throw, but for which the compiler cannot determine so on its own. Should I append noexcept to the function declaration in all such cases?

Short answer: It depends on your role and how you use C++. Not every user needs to understand every bit of the code.

For the author of a library, it is easy to decide which methods will not throw even before implementing them (*If the author specifies first and implements later*). For example, if one is implementing a `vector` and is declaring three methods:

- `num()` that returns the number of elements,
- `empty()` that returns if the vector is empty, and
- `insert()` to insert an element into the vector.

Then, the author will generally know for certain that only `insert()` may throw as it involves allocating memory but the other two only reads from memory that he has complete control. Therefore, putting `noexcept` in methods that will not throw comes very natural to the author, if the author cares about the performance of his library.

In contrast, for an ordinary library user that occasionally writes wrapper functions and methods, the user might not have and might not need to have a comprehensive understanding of the code he writes. For example, if one is using C++ to scrap some webpages, and is calling various functions to establish HTTP connections, iterate through the HTML documents, etc., then the user does not need to understand precisely when the functions will throw or not. The user might not understand how the network works --- he only needs to know the functions can achieve what he wants.

On this occasion, it does not matter much if the user puts `noexcept` in his custom functions or not.