# Can I mark a classes move-operation noexcept if it contains a standard container?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, move-semantics, noexcept

**The idiomatic way to implement move-operations on classes with a standard container member can not be `noexcept`** and therefore will not be movable by operations like `vector.push_back()`. Or am I mistaken?

To get speed from

```
vector<Elem> data;
// ...
data.push_back( elem );
```

We are encouraged to make out move operations `noexcept` -- so during the vectors resize the library can safely move elements to the reallocated storage.

```
class Elem {
    // ...
    Elem(Elem&&) noexcept;            // noexcept important for move
    Elem& operator=(Elem&&) noexcept; // noexcept important for move
};
```

So far so good, now my `elem`s can be pushed-back much faster.

But: If I add a container as member, can my class be still be marked noexcept-move? All standard containers do *not* have their move `noexcept`!

```
class Stuff {
    vector<int> bulk;
    // ...
    Stuff(Stuff&& o)  // !!! no noexcept because of vector-move  
      : bulk(move(o.bulk))
      {}
    Stuff& operator=(Stuff&&) // !!! no noexcept...
      { /* appropriate implementation */ }
};
```

This also means, that we can also not rely on the compiler-generated move-operations, right? The following complete class will also not have `noexcept`-move-operations and therefore not be "fast", correct?

```
struct Holder {
    vector<int> bulk;
};
```

Maybe `vector<int>` is a bit too simple to move, but what about `vector<Elem>`?

This would have great consequences on all data structures with containers as members.

Comment: Part of the problem is the unknowns of allocator traits.  You would think that `std::vector::swap()` could be `noexcept` as well.

Comment: Even though the standard container's member functions have no required noexcept-specification, they have exception guarantees. If those guarantees say that operation does not throw, you can make your own move ctor noexcept "safely".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I feel your pain, really.

Some std::implementations will mark the move members of containers as `noexcept`, at least conditional on the allocator properties, as an extension.  You can adapt your code to automatically take advantage of these extensions, for example:

```
class Stuff {
    std::vector<int> bulk;
    // ...
public:
    Stuff(Stuff&& o)
      noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::vector<int>>::value)
      : bulk(std::move(o.bulk))
      {}
    Stuff& operator=(Stuff&&)
      noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<std::vector<int>>::value)
      { /* appropriate implementation */ }
};
```

And you can even test whether or not your type does have noexcept move members:

```
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Stuff>::value,
                     "I hope Stuff has noexcept move members");
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<Stuff>::value,
                     "I hope Stuff has noexcept move members");
```

[libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org) in particular does have noexcept move members for all of its containers, whenever the allocator allows, and `std::allocator` always allows the container move members to be noexcept.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about what the compiler generates for `struct Holder;`? I figure that class will have an unefficient move, ie. a copying one? The compiler will not include an conditional `noexcept`, I presume. (And if I were to continue Scott's joke, I would ask if there is a downloadable binary for  [Windows](http://libcxx.llvm.org/results.Windows.html), yet. But I won't ;-)

Comment: Actually the `noexcept` spec for `Holder` will be exactly as I've recommended you explicitly do for `Stuff`.  Indeed, you could also just use `= default`.  And you can test `Holder`'s `noexcept` spec in the exact same manner I've shown for `Stuff`.  Specifically, if the move constructor for `vector<int>` is `noexcept`, then the implicit move constructor of `Holder` will also be `noexcept`.

Comment: I am relieved. This is what [§12.9](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18654089/472245) states with its many words, I gather.

Comment: @HowardHinnant The test might be a bit misleading because it can also catch `noexcept` copy constructors; see comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18654089/1046167

Comment: If the copy constructor is to be used to do the move, the `is_nothrow_move_` traits are still the right tool to ask the question (by design).

Comment: The same issue confused the committee a decade ago and was fixed by renaming the traits by this paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3142.html

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the allocator that your standard container is using. The default allocator `std::allocator<T>` is guaranteed not to throw on copy (and has no move constructor), which in turn means that the container will not throw on move.

One interesting feature of `noexcept` compared with the deprecated `throw()` is that you can use an expression that is evaluated at compile time. The exact condition to be tested might not be trivial though...