# The three std::complex specializations and noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have a C++17 question about `std::complex<float>`, `std::complex<double>`, and `std::complex<long double>` and their member functions `real()` and `imag()`.

Obviously, these member functions cannot throw an exception as they just return a value by copy of built-in floating-point type.

So why are they not specified `noexcept`?

Comment: For polymorphism with any other specializations anyone may choose to create?

Comment: No, that's not it: "The effect of instantiating the template complex for any type other than float, double, or long double is unspecified."

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21331592/2788450) but the context is slightly different. The way `noexcept` is generally specified by the standard library is to do so only when it would be potentially beneficial. Keep in mind that a function lacking `noexpect` specification may still be called from within a `noexcept` function (unlike the analogous situation for `const`), so omitting `noexcept` is not restrictive in any way. Merely, `noexcept` indicates to the compiler that no exception handling is necessary/possible which *can* convey dramatic performance benefits, especially in situations where the compiler can only reason on the function based on its signature. However `std::complex::(real|imag)` are both likely to be inlined anyway and the exception handling can be elided in that case anyway.

That being said, I can also not see anything wrong with declaring `noexcept` in this case. Generally, one should be cautious not to declare any library API `noexcept` as this potentially restricts implementators. In the case of `std::complex`, however, the wiggle room for implementations is so narrow that it is fair to stipulate that no exceptions could be thrown. My guess is that, `std::complex` predating `noexcept`, there was never enough of a reason to add `noexcept` specifiers retroactively.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean a compiler optimization like inlining might "correct" a constant expression like the `noexcept` operator? That is, although `noexcept(std::complex<double>{}.real())` yields `false` due to the missing `noexcept` specifier, the branch for `true` might still be taken because an optimizing compiler knows better? I somehow doubt that the C++ standard relies on that concept. For example, what happens with code in a DLL that is not statically linked? No compiler can optimize in that case and the `noexcept` specifier would be the only way to enable the branch for `true`.