# Why doesn't N3421 provide the noexcept qualifier?

Tags: c++, std, function-object, c++14

In [N3421 - Making Operator Functors greater<>](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421), the new specialization for the std function objects is:

```
template <> struct plus<void> {
  template <class T, class U> auto operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const
  -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u));
};
```

instead of

```
template <> struct plus<void> {
  template <class T, class U> auto operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const
  noexcept(noexcept(decltype(std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u))
                     (std::move(std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u)))))
  -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u));
};
```

- Is there a reason for that?
- Does the omission of `noexcept` matter in this use case?

Edit: [link to the working draft line in github](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/source/utilities.tex#L7576).

Edit 2: [link to libc++ plus specialization](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/functional#L502).

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/10788136/332733

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The existing LWG guidelines do not encourage the use of noexcept. They do not accept noexcept on wide-contract functions, only narrow-contract ones. I don't recall exactly how these terms were defined, but I can tell you that I was present at the Bristol meeting discussing `noexcept` and they refused to place it on a function because it was wide-contract, which I considered to be batshit insane.

So it's probably not on here for one of two reasons. The first is that the Committee and paper authors are not yet used to considering `noexcept` in every case- similar to `constexpr`. In this case, the paper author (STL) probably simply forgot to add it.

The second is that LWG has some insane over-restrictions on when they will accept `noexcept`.

Comment: I've accepted this as an answer since it led me to the following: [Conservative use of noexcept in the 
Library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf).

Comment: Wow, that's troubling. "preferring their use be left as a library vendor quality-of-implementation feature until we have more experience" is somewhat understandable, but not if vendors aren't allowed to add `noexcept` where it makes sense, and the as-if rule doesn't permit them to do so.

Comment: @hvd In this particular case, I think that vendors might add it as an extension.

Comment: @gnzlbg If valid programs can tell the difference, it's not allowed as an extension. Extensions must only affect programs using that extension.

Comment: You are right, they might provide a macro to activate this kind of extension so that they can get experience with this.

Comment: The intent of the committee is to permit vendors to add noexcept if they wish.  From n3797 17.6.5.12 Restrictions on exception handling: "An implementation may strengthen the exception-specification for a non-virtual function by adding a non-throwing noexcept specification."

Comment: @Nevin Ah, good, thanks for finding that. This *seems* to allow implementations to add `noexcept` to functions that do throw exceptions and are intended to throw exceptions (based on the wording in the standard -- perhaps it's been slightly altered in n3797), but I can live with the assumption that no implementation would make that mistake. :)

Answer (score 4):

@DeadMG's answer led me to [Conservative use of noexcept in the Library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf), which says the following:

> Adopted Guidelines
>
> - No library destructor should throw. They shall use the implicitly supplied (non- throwing) exception specification.
> - Each library function having a wide contract, that the LWG agree cannot throw, should be marked as unconditionally noexcept.
> - If a library swap function, move-constructor, or move-assignment operator is conditionally-wide (i.e. can be proven to not throw by
>     applying the noexcept operator) then it should be marked as
>     conditionally noexcept. No other function should use a conditional
>     noexcept specification.
> - Library functions designed for compatibility with “C” code (such as the atomics facility), may be marked as unconditionally noexcept.

where narrow and wide contracts are defined as:

> - A wide contract for a function or operation does not specify any undeﬁned behavior.  Such a contract has no preconditions: A function
>     with a wide contract places no  additional runtime constraints on its
>     arguments, on any object state, nor on any  external global state.
> - A narrow contract is a contract which is not wide. Narrow contracts for a functions or operations result in undefined behavior when called
>     in a manner that violates the documented contract. Such a contract
>     specifies at least one precondition involving its arguments, object
>     state, or some external global state, such as the initialization of a
>     static object.

At the end of that document, operators functors previously marked `noexcept` are no longer `noexcept`.

So if I understand this correctly, the new operators functors in `<functional>` have wide-contracts, but might throw sometimes depending on the types they act on. As such, they are not unconditionally `noexcept(true)`. Due to this, it is left to the library implementors to decide:

> their use be left as a library vendor quality-of-implementation
>   feature until we have more  experience.