# Why is std::pair not nothrow constructible?

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics, nothrow

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    std::string s;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha << is_nothrow_constructible<Foo>::value << endl;
    cout << is_nothrow_constructible<pair<string, int>>::value << endl;

    cout << is_nothrow_move_constructible<Foo>::value << endl;
    cout << is_nothrow_move_constructible<pair<string, int>>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

produces the following output when compiled with `g++ -std=c++11`:

```
true
false
true
true
```

Why is `std::pair<string, int>` not nothrow constructible, while `Foo` is, and why it is nothrow move constructible?

Comment: Do you want a reason the commite did what it did or are you looking for an answer like: because the standard says it isn't?  If you look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) you will see non of the constructors are `noexcept`

Comment: Theory: `Foo`'s compiler-provided constructors automatically propagate the nothrow-ness of the constructors they call. `std::pair`'s constructors are explicitly declared and the standard doesn't require them to propagate nothrow-ness. I don't think there's a reason they couldn't be made to, they just don't.

Comment: @NathanOliver I would like to know what is the reason behind it, also, even if not stated on your link, the move ctor is apparently nothrow constructible.

Comment: @cdhowie `std::pair::pair` _"...Does not throw exceptions unless one of the specified operations (e.g. constructor of an element) throws...._ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair

Comment: @Nick I'm going to go out on a limb and say that is your compiler being nice to you.  `std::vector` requires the move constructor to be `noexcept` for it to move elements when resizing and your implmentation knows that and marked it as such so you can get the performance gain.  Most likely this is defect in the standard since we have conditional `noexcept` specifers.

Comment: It is a pain to make everything conditionally noexcept, especially without `noexcept(auto)`, so the standard only specifies it in rare cases, and implementations only add it where the benefit is clear.

Comment: @RichardCritten "Does not throw exceptions" is a very different thing from "is declared not to throw exceptions."

Comment: A similar question with interesting answers [Why doesn't N3421 provide the noexcept specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752446/why-doesnt-n3421-provide-the-noexcept-qualifier)

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly enough, [none of the constructors is declared noexcept under any conditions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair). Likely a typical Standard defect (only the textual description below promises to not throw any exceptions if none of the elements does.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, defaulted constructors are defined as `noexcept` whenever possible. However, `std::pair` has default constructor defined without `noexcept` (i.e. not `nothrow`). You can check it yourself [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).

You can see the default constructor for `std::pair` is defined without `noexcept` (first item from the link), and move constructor for `std::pair` is defaulted (8th item from the link).

Since you have not declared/defined any constructor for `Foo`, its constructors are defaults, therefore `noexcept`.

Comment: The really doesn't answer what the OP wants to know.  Yes it shows that it is not defined to be so but why was that decision made, and why does their implementation say it is nothrow move constructable?

Comment: @NathanOliver It is because the member types can have default constructor that can throw, and we cannot have both nothrow and throw version of default constructor of `std::pair`. The move constructor is defaulted and follows the standard.

Comment: But we can have conditional `noexcept` specifiers so you can specify it to be `noexcept` when the underlying types are `noexcept`.

Comment: @ccld44 *"we cannot have both nothrow and throw version of default constructor"* Not on the same type, but we can define a template type for which an instantiation's constructor can be nothrow or throw depending on the type parameters. Such a thing is possible here.

Comment: @NathanOliver You are right. It is possible that conditional `noexcept` for the default constructor can solve the issue. I see that `std::vector` is doing what you described.