# How to use noexcept in C++ or How does it work?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

I am unable to understand the use & purpose of the `noexcept` keyword in C++11/14. I understand that it is a signature for a function that does not emit `exceptions`. But does it really work?

Look at this code below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void seev (vector<int> &v) noexcept;
void seev (vector<int> &v) noexcept
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        cout<<v.at(i)<<' ';
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5};
    seev(v);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code will surely throw an `out_of_range exception`. So the use of `noexcept` here is useless, or is it?

My queries are :

1. How does `noexcept` work?
2. How is it used?
3. What `throw()` wasn't able to do that `noexcept` could?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I really use noexcept?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787766/when-should-i-really-use-noexcept)

Comment: Helpful information can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079903/noexcept-stack-unwinding-and-performance) and especially in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26080332/1969455).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec#Notes):

> A noexcept specification on a function is merely a method for a
> programmer to inform the compiler whether or not a function should
> throw exceptions.
>
> The compiler can use this information to enable certain optimizations
> on non-throwing functions as well as enable the noexcept operator,
> which can check at compile time if a particular expression is declared
> to throw any exceptions.
>
> For example, containers such as std::vector will move their elements
> if the elements' move constructor is noexcept, and copy otherwise
> (unless the copy constructor is not accessible, but a potentially
> throwing move constructor is, in which case the strong exception
> guarantee is waived).
>
> noexcept is an improved version of throw(), which is deprecated in
> C++11. Unlike throw(), noexcept will not call std::unexpected and may
> or may not unwind the stack, which potentially allows the compiler to
> implement noexcept without the runtime overhead of throw().

For more details, please visit below websites

- https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/noexcept-what-for/
- [When should I really use noexcept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787766/when-should-i-really-use-noexcept)

Edit: Sample source code to illustrate above points.

```
// whether foo is declared noexcept depends on if the expression
// T() will throw any exceptions, check in compile time
template <class T>
void foo() noexcept(noexcept(T())) {     
}
 
void bar() noexcept(true) {    
}

void baz() noexcept {
    throw 42;     
}  // noexcept is the same as noexcept(true)
 
int main() 
{
    foo<int>();  // noexcept(noexcept(int())) => noexcept(true), so this is fine
 
    bar();  // fine
    baz();  // compiles, but at runtime this calls std::terminate
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I'm posting 2 pieces of code to explain your problem:

Code 1:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo() noexcept     // see the noexcept specifier
{
    throw 42;
}
int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cerr<<"exception caught\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here the output will be:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

If I remove the `noexcept`then:

Code 2:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo()    // noexcept is eliminated
{
    throw 42;
}
int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cerr<<"exception caught\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

```
exception caught
```

Because `foo` was signed as `noexcept`, hence `terminate` was called.

Inheriting constructors and the implicitly-declared default constructors, copy constructors, move constructors, destructors, copy-assignment operators, and move-assignment operators are all `noexcept(true)` by default, unless they are required to call a function that is `noexcept(false)`, in which case these functions are `noexcept(false)`.

You can also write lines like:

```
cout << boolalpha << noexcept(foo);   // here noexcept acts as 
                                     // an operator instead of a specifier
```

The above line will check if `foo` will throw an `exception` or not. If it would throw then the return value will be `true` else `false`.

You can read more about these in this: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.dk/2014/03/declare-functions-noexcept-whenever.html

Comment: I think it's strong to claim the first result "will be" - that's very much an implementation-defined error message.

Answer (score 9):

`noexcept` indicates that a function is intended not to to throw an exception, a guarantee you as a developer provides, that is not enforced by the compiler. So using it in a situation where your function calls functions that might throw exceptions that you do not catch yourself is bad.

The whole range of `throw()` specifiers were removed because the exception specifiers were less than optimal in C++, see: [Difference between C++03 throw() specifier C++11 noexcept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833241/difference-between-c03-throw-specifier-c11-noexcept)

`noexcept` has the advantage of not stating which exception is thrown, but rather whether an exception is thrown or not. It accepts a parameter which may be `false` if you expect the function to throw an exception.

The uses of this, can be in for instance an inherited class structure, where one super class wish to "enforce" to an inherited class, that a specific virtual function is not allowed to throw an exception. Further more the compiler may use the information for optimization.

`noexcept` is also an operator which can evaluate an expression and return whether or not that expression may thrown an exception or not, as per § 5.3.7.

> 5.3.7 noexcept operator [expr.unary.noexcept]
>
> 1 The noexcept operator determines whether the evaluation of its operand, which is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5), can throw an exception (15.1).
>   noexcept-expression:
>   noexcept ( expression )
>
> 2 The result of the noexcept operator is a constant of type bool and is an rvalue.
>
> 3 The result of the noexcept operator is false if in a potentially-evaluated context the expression would
>   contain
>
> — a potentially-evaluated call to a function, member function, function pointer, or member function pointer that does not have a non-throwing exception-specification (15.4), unless the call is a constant
>   expression (5.19),
>   — a potentially-evaluated throw-expression (15.1),
>   — a potentially-evaluated dynamic_cast expression dynamic_cast(v), where T is a reference type, that requires a run-time check (5.2.7), or
>   — a potentially-evaluated typeid expression (5.2.8) applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type (10.3).
>   Otherwise, the result is true.

I can't explain the possible optimizations as well as Scott Meyers: http://aristeia.com/EC++11-14/noexcept%202014-03-31.pdf from his blog post: [Declare functions noexcept whenever possible?](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.dk/2014/03/declare-functions-noexcept-whenever.html)

> The difference between unwinding the call stack and possibly unwinding it has a surprisingly large impact on code generation. In a noexcept function, optimizers need not keep the runtime stack in an unwindable state if an exception would propagate out of the function, nor must they ensure that objects in a noexcept function are destroyed in the inverse order of construction should an exception leave the function. *The result is more opportunities for optimization*, not only within the body of a noexcept function, but also at sites where the function is called. Such flexibility is present only for noexcept functions. Functions with “throw()” exception specifications lack it, as do functions with no exception specification at all.

Comment: then it seems useless

Comment: The compiler can perform optimizations if `noexcept` is present which otherwise would yield invalid code. This regards unwinding the stack in case of an exception.

Comment: it's not useless. Compilers can make advantage of noexcept and create mote optimized code. Generally code internally behaves in a different way, when there is or there is not noexcept word.

Comment: could you plz elaborate @DawidPi

Comment: what kind of optimizations @TommyA ?

Comment: Hi @AnkitAcharya I knew I had read some post by Scott Meyers regarding it not long ago, I managed to find it, and have quoted him now :) should describe pretty well how it can affect optimization.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya No, at a minimum it is a clear statement of intent by the developer to users about the API and what it guarantees, and beyond that it can also enable optimisations, in particular moving instead of copying where a `noexcept` move constructor exists. So it is far from useless.