# How does noexcept in C++ change the assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-optimization, noexcept

How does noexcept in C++ change the assembly? I tried a bit with small functions, in godbolt, but [the assembly did not change](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'float+pi()+%0A//noexcept+//+no+difference%0A%7B+return+3.14%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++float+b%7B0%7D%3B%0A++++b+%3D+pi()%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

```c++
float pi() 
//noexcept // no difference
{ return 3.14; }

int main(){
    float b{0};
    b = pi();
    return 0;
}
```

I am looking for a minimal working example, where I can see a change in the assembly due to `noexcept`.

Comment: In certain cases, it can be a massive change, such as with `std::vector<MyType>` where if `MyType`'s move constructor is not `noexcept`, `std::vector` has to copy the elements when it resizes, rather than just move them. In other cases, as you've seen, it can make no difference. In short, `noexcept` doesn't "change the assembly", but it provides semantic meaning that library code can rely on, which can eventually cause significant changes in the assembly, or no changes in the assembly.

Comment: The body of a `noexcept` function may also be compiled in a much more optimized way, since local variables won't need to be destroyed correctly in the case of an exception. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079903/noexcept-stack-unwinding-and-performance

Comment: Your example is too simple, the compiler knew already it is noexcept, without you telling it. Use a more complex example, for example calling a further function that is in another code file, so the compiler cannot see it is for sure noexcept.

Comment: Of course the `noexcept` statement might also result in a different assembly code for the **calling** function (especially if that function contains a `try`-`catch` statement).

Comment: `noexcept` really only makes a difference when A) there are destructors to run so there are non-trivial items to destruct B) exceptions *could* be thrown and thus the compiler would have to handle those cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple examples [can be constructed](https://www.godbolt.org/z/MsmafZ) that involve destructors directly rather than introspection on `noexcept` status:

```
void a(int);
void b() noexcept;
void c(int i) {
  struct A {
    int i;
    ~A() {a(i);}
  } a={i};
  b();
  a.i=1;
}
```

Here, the `noexcept` allows the initialization of `a` in the **caller** to be ignored, since the destructor cannot observe it.

```
struct B {~B();};
void f();
void g() noexcept {
  B b1;
  f();
  B b2;
}
```

Here, the `noexcept` allows the omission of frame information needed in case the **callee** throws.  This depends on the (very common) decision to not unwind the stack when calling `std::terminate`.