# Is it necessary to write noexcept for a function that does almost nothing?

Tags: c++

If I have something like this

```
struct A{
    int x;
    constexpr A() : x(0){}
    constexpr void set(){ x = 0; }
    constexpr bool check()const{ return x == 5; }
};
```

Does writing `set` and `check` as `noexcept` make any good/difference?

To generalize: do I need to write functions, that only perform operations on integral types, as `noexcept` ?

Comment: Depends on how you intend to use your data structure and those functions.  Declaring those function `noexcept` makes life easier if they are called from a large, complicated function that is also specified as `noexcept`.    If they aren't called from such a function, it's up to you.

Comment: @Peter, I thought, since all of them are going to be inlined, the compiler will check the operations inside the function for `noexcept`, because it will do so anyway; and in case with operations on integral types they will be deduced `noexcept`, making my `noexcept` redundant

Comment: You're making some grand assumptions about what analysis a compiler will do.

Comment: I always regarded this keyword as more of a hint to the human maintaners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`noexcept` serves two purposes: it describes an **interface**, and it improves **performance**.  The first is important even when the function is trivial, in that it documents that (in all compatible versions) it will *stay* non-throwing even if the implementation becomes more complex (and perhaps stops being inline).  That property is important for clients that want to write exception-safe code (and changing it can silently break them).

The second has two components: while direct [code generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56792966/8586227) may be unaffected when the body is simple and available, the library behavior associated with a type depends only on its declaration (which is a good thing, given the interface idea).  Libraries tend to check the potential for throwing from only a few functions (especially the special member functions), so that’s unlikely to matter in this case, but do note that the space of “special” functions grows over time (*e.g.*, `swap`, `operator==`).

The conclusion is that you should write `noexcept` when it’s important—either to your human readers or to your analyzing libraries.