# Resize on std::vector does not call move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move

I have been playing around with std::vector to understand when objects are constructed, destructed, copy constructed and move constructed. To so do, I have written the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        std::cout << "Constructor called for " << this << std::endl;
    }
    Test(const Test& x) {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor called for " << this << std::endl;
    }
    Test(Test&& x) {
        std::cout << "Move Constructor called for " << this << std::endl;
    }
    ~Test() {
        std::cout << "Destructor called for " << this << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Test> a( 1 );
    a.resize(3);

    return 0;
}
```

When a is resized, reallocation happens. My guess would have been that the object a[0] is moved constructed to the new a[0]. But, with libc++ and libstdc++, it seems that the copy constructor is called and not the move constructor. Is there any reason for such a behaviour?

Answer (score 15):

I just found the answer to the question. The move constructor has to be declared noexcept to do so. When such a change has been done

```
Test(Test&& x) noexcept {
    std::cout << "Move Constructor called for " << this << std::endl;
}
```

the move constructor is called.

Comment: you'd think the optimiser should deduce that your constructor doesn't throw and use it even without the noexcept specifier.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Does the compiler _ever_ infer modifiers? It doesn't for `const` (as a postfix).

Comment: @gbjbaanb I think you technically could make `cout` throw via [`ios::exceptions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).

Comment: @gbjbaanb: The optimizer should not alter the meaning of the code. Deducing `noexcept` would be nice feature, but the standard does not include it.

Comment: I did read it somewhere when I was looking up the spec.. ah [in Pubby's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787766/when-should-i-really-use-noexcept?rq=1). What is interesting is that the compiler-generated move constructor does not have noexcept apparently. Its times like this that I think C++ has gone too far into 'overcomplex' territory as its detractors claim. :-(

Comment: @gbjbaanb, why do you think the implicit move constructor for `Test` would not be `noexcept`? [Did you try it?](http://ideone.com/a27jPa) It has no members and no bases, so the implicit move ctor would be empty, and deduced as `noexcept`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I guess it depends on the compiler - I read it on t'internet that the default one didn't include it. And here in comments, I'm told that the standard does not include deducing such things :-)  I'm also at work and stuck on VS2010, so no, I haven't tried it. :-( What I am sure of is that it is something that is inducing a lot of confusion, which isn't a good thing for the language to thrive.

Answer (score 4):

Just as @InsideLoop's answer said, the move constructor has to be declared "noexcept" to be called.

It is because in the vector::resize() function call stack, we can find **move_if_noexcept()** is called in function **__construct_backward()**.(see [your library path]/include/c++/v1/memory line:1531)

```
construct(__a, _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(__end2-1), _VSTD::move_if_noexcept(*--__end1));
```

According to the C++11 standard, we know that move constructor is used for temporary right value in normal. So the move constructor throwing exception is such a dangerous thing, and we can declare "noexcept" for the move constructor to avoid it.

Using **move_if_noexcept()**, although it loss in performance, but can make the process safe. And the function will activate the move constructor when move constructor is declared "noexcept".

(Sorry for my poor English.)