# Should I write noexcept only to constructors and move operators?

Tags: c++, c++11

There is a quite (very) [popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787766/) about the usage of `noexcept`, but it's from 8 years ago, and other popular answers are just as old. Seeing some code from other people in different projects, it seems to me that `noexcept` didn't become a very common thing for many developers to write.

Besides move constructor and move assignment operator, the benefit of using `noexcept` doesn't seems clear enough to think about for every function ("should I add `noexcept` here or not?").

Has somebody found a good usage of this specifier, and can share their experience?

Comment: From a gamedev perspective: "`noexcept` all the things!" o/

Comment: @Casey glad somebody found it useful for themselves :-)

Answer (score 5):

Besides the answers in the question that you linked (which continue to be relevant today), there are quite a few specific cases called out in the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) that you might want to check out:

- [F.6: If your function must not throw, declare it `noexcept`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-noexcept)
- [C.37: Make destructors `noexcept`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-dtor-noexcept)
- [C.66: Make move operations `noexcept`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-move-noexcept)
- [C.85: Make `swap` `noexcept`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-swap-noexcept)
- [C.86: Make `==` symmetric with respect of operand types and `noexcept`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-eq)
- [C.89: Make a `hash` `noexcept`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-hash)
- [E.12: Use `noexcept` when exiting a function because of a `throw` is impossible or unacceptable](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Re-noexcept)

It's not a topic to easily summarize as noted by the continued lack of content (as of 03-2021) in the [Discussion: Usage of `noexcept`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#discussion-usage-of-noexcept) section.

Comment: answers that link to other sites don't make for good answers on SO,  your answer should be self contained and links provide additional/related info

Comment: @KeithNicholas Answers that link to the defacto standard for how-to writing C++ are actually good. Each of his points is clearly expressed in English as well as providing links.

Comment: @MartinYork sure, if the answer also contains the relevant information

Comment: @KeithNicholas They seem to. Each point is clear english sentence.