# Move which throws?

Tags: c++, exception, move-semantics

To my understanding, move-constructors and move-assign must be marked noexcept in order for the compiler to utilize them when, for example, reallocating inside a vector.

However, is there any real-world case where a move-assign, move-construct might actually throw?

*Update*:

Classes that for example has an allocated resource when constructed cant be no-throw move.

Comment: I was wondering the same for move. But why nothrow swap?

Comment: @BЈовић: You need a non-throwing swap to get a strong exception guarantee from [copy-and-swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543) and similar idioms.

Comment: Stream objects' move constructors can throw.

Comment: @jrok why would they throw?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> However, is there any real-world case where a move-assign,
>   move-construct (or swap) might actually throw?

Yes.  Consider an implementation of `std::list`.  The `end` iterator must point "one past the last element" in the list.  There exist implementations of `std::list` where what `end` points to is a dynamically allocated node.  Even the default constructor allocates such a node so that when you call `end()`, there is something to point to.

In such an implementation, *every* constructor must allocate a node for `end()` to point to… even the move constructor.  That allocation may fail, and throw an exception.

This same behavior can extend to any node-based container.

There are also implementations of these node-based containers that do a "short-string" optimization:  They embed the end node within the container class itself, instead of dynamically allocating.  Thus the default constructor (and move constructor) need not allocate anything.

The move assignment operator can throw for any `container<X>` if for the container's allocator `propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is false, and if the allocator in the lhs is not equal to the allocator in the rhs.  In that case the move assignment operator  is forbidden from transferring memory ownership from the rhs to the lhs.  This can not happen if you are using `std::allocator`, as all instances of `std::allocator` are equal to one another.

**Update**

Here is a conforming and portable example of the case when `propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is false.  It has been tested against the latest version of VS, gcc and clang.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class allocator
{
    int id_;
public:
    using value_type    = T;

    allocator(int id) noexcept : id_(id) {}
    template <class U> allocator(allocator<U> const& u) noexcept : id_(u.id_) {}

    value_type*
    allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        return static_cast<value_type*>(::operator new (n*sizeof(value_type)));
    }

    void
    deallocate(value_type* p, std::size_t) noexcept
    {
        ::operator delete(p);
    }

    template <class U, class V>
    friend
    bool
    operator==(allocator<U> const& x, allocator<V> const& y) noexcept
    {
        return x.id_ == y.id_;
    }
};

template <class T, class U>
bool
operator!=(allocator<T> const& x, allocator<U> const& y) noexcept
{
    return !(x == y);
}

template <class T> using vector = std::vector<T, allocator<T>>;

struct A
{
    static bool time_to_throw;

    A() = default;
    A(const A&) {if (time_to_throw) throw 1;}
    A& operator=(const A&) {if (time_to_throw) throw 1; return *this;}
};

bool A::time_to_throw = false;

int
main()
{
    vector<A> v1(5, A{}, allocator<A>{1});
    vector<A> v2(allocator<A>{2});
    v2 = std::move(v1);
    try
    {
        A::time_to_throw = true;
        v1 = std::move(v2);
        assert(false);
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

This program outputs:

```
1
```

which indicates that the `vector<T, A>` move assignment operator is copy/moving its elements when `propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is false and the two allocators in question do not compare equal.  If any of those copies/moves throws, then the container move assignment throws.

Comment: Hehe, come to think about it, I've written a Copy-On-Write class myself which also has a throwing move as it always has to have an object allocated.

Comment: Hmm, still no swap that throws thou

Comment: But why would you need to allocate a new object if you can just steal the one you're moving from? Unless you want to leave the moves from object in a valid state that is, but do you really need to do that?

Comment: I didn't find these examples very convincing. For the `std::list` it's possible to move the dynamically allocated node as well. There is no need to allocate on move unless you want to keep the moved-from object in some zombie (partially usable) state. The other one is a programmer error (can't assign an incompatible allocator), and deserves std::terminate().

Comment: @ValentinMilea:  Feel free to take your designs to the implementors of Visual Studio and gcc: http://howardhinnant.github.io/container_summary

Comment: @ValentinMilea:  You should read up on `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` before spreading misinformation.  Here is a convenience link for you: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf

Answer (score 9):

Yes, throwing move constructors exist in the wild. Consider `std::pair<T, U>` where `T` is noexcept-movable, and `U` is only copyable (assume that copies can throw). Then you have a useful `std::pair<T, U>` move constructor which may throw.

There is a `std::move_if_noexcept` utility in the standard library if you need (useful to implement `std::vector::resize` with at least the basic exception guarantee).

See also [Move constructors and the Strong Exception Guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011428/move-constructors-and-the-strong-exception-guarantee)

Answer (score 1):

Move constructors on classes with `const` data members can also throw. Check [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/8wbeom/coding_guideline_avoid_const_member_variables/) for more info.